# Correct way to change repository location for gitosis?

Tags: gitosis, apt-get, ubuntu-server

What is the recommended way to change the repository location from /srv/gitosis in Gitosis installed via apt-get (on Ubuntu Server 11.04)? I have currently solved it by changing the home dir for the gitosis user and relinking the "git" symlink found in /srv/gitosis/git to match the new location. I am a bit concerned what will happen when Gitosis is updated using apt-get, will this reset these paths?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gitosis is abandonware, and has been for 2 years now. Use Gitolite instead, which is also packaged by Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, so I switched to gitolite. Same question as above, how do I change the repository location reliably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out you CAN actually answer your own question. That's great! (I first wrote the answer in a comment to my question, but this is better.)

There's a variable you can set in .gitolite.rc called $REPO_BASE. Just change this to where you want to store your repositories. To me, that seems to be the correct way to do it.

NOTE: This answer is for Gitolite, as that's what I started using instead of Gitosis (as per the first comment to my question)! Still not sure about a correct way to change it for Gitosis, although my "solution" in the question worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the `--base-path` in the git-daemon and restarted the daemon.

```
mkdir /data/git
mkdir /data/git/repositories
chown -R git:git /data/git
chmod 770 /data/git/

nano /etc/conf.d/git-daemon (GITDAEMON_OPTS="--syslog --base-path=/data/git/repositories/"; GIT_USER="git"; GIT_GROUP="git"); 

/etc/init.d/git-daemon restart
```

After that all your repositories will be served from `/data/git/repositories`.

In case you use gitolite, you can move the gitolite-admin.git repo to the new location:

```
cp -vR /var/lib/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/ /data/git/repositories/
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future generations: this guy describes the process in detail:
http://sharagoz.com/posts/3-changing-the-repository-location-for-gitosis

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gitosis` but it is better to keep user name the same